# Calculate the distance like the Google Maps in longitude and latitude origin and longitude and latitude final

Tags: python, google-maps

I have the follow df with the columns:

```
lati_origin longi_oringin lati_final longi_final
-19.864315   -44.047180   -3.026643   -59.955860
```

I used the follow function, but don't return the same distance in km of Google Maps.

```
def haversine_np(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)

    All args must be of equal length.    

    """
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1
    dlat = lat2 - lat1

    a = np.sin(dlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(dlon/2.0)**2

    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    km = 6371 * c
    return km
```

Can someone help me calculate the distance similar the Google Maps from my df?

Comment: why can't you use a packages here ?

Comment: Are you expecting driving distance?  Please provide the answer you get and the answer you expect (and perhaps a link to the Google Map displaying the distance)

Comment: @geocodezip I need create a new column in my df with the similar distance of the Google maps of different longitudes and latitudes. With my function the distance are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`geopy`](https://pypi.org/project/geopy/) to find the distance

```
import geopy.distance

def calculte_distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    coords_1 = (lat1, lon1)
    coords_2 = (lat2, lon2)
    return geopy.distance.geodesic(coords_1, coords_2).km
```

Installation

```
pip install geopy
```

Execution:

```
In [1]: calculte_distance(-44.047180,-19.864315,-59.955860,-3.026643)
Out[1]: 2541.261913716022
```

Comment: I used the follow code: `calculte_distance(df_part4.longitude, df_part4.latitude, df_part4.longitude_x, df_part4.latitude_x)` , but return this error: `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` I need create the new column with the distances

Comment: It could be values from df not coming as expected. Updated my answer the sample execution with the values mentioned in your question.